# How to call lib method from WinRT(Metro style) app

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, static-libraries

I have a project (executable) written for Win32. I changed it to be a static lib project, so that it compiles for WinRT.
Now I have a Metro Style app and I need to call the main() method of that lib from my app and get results.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to 
1.redefine the main() of the executable:
define main < name >
2. declare it as an extern in my Metro app:
extern int < name >(< arguments if any >);
3. call it:
< name >(< arguments if any >);